# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet. Django 3.1.4

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn about Django and REST framework and starting customize my model but went I use makemigration it show this error can someone lease help me out.
This is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms, TextInput

class AccountManager(BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password = None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Username cannot be empty')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Email cannot be empty')
        user = self.model(username = username,email = self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_super_user(self, username, email, password = None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Password cannot be empty')

        user = self.create_user(username,email,password)
        user.is_super_user = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField('settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL', max_length=300, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)# only for superuser
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = AccountManager()



    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

And this this the error

```
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, this error happens when you have circular imports in your code

Comment: Do you have any text in your app's **__init__.py** file?

Comment: I don't have any text in my app's _init_.py